# Qt and dynamic library sample code

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

i wanted to create a software which conforms to the following structure:

A GUI window , and many Qt dynamic libraries , which exports function interface.

So two things to clear out , how to make a plugin for Qt apps , and how to load them , load the exported function by them.

Many thanks !

Comment: This question is very broad indeed IMHO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[How to Create Qt Plugins](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/plugins-howto.html)

Comment: Politeness is a virtue. I considered hitting the delete button on this, but decided to just clean it up instead.

Comment: Note that instead of outright down-voting the question I tried to give a productive answer and still express my annoyance, that some people ask questions without even trying to read the documentation or googling the answer.  What annoys me even more is, that some people start to wage down-vote wars - this will end with a lot of people not willing to help anymore and will make the vote system completely useless.

Comment: @Robert: It could be a matter of discussion if RTFM with its long historical tradition in the IT must be considered impolite. Despite the bad f-word it contains, it became part of the 'matter of fact' style that somehow is a fundamental part of IT culture. (Though Jens could have added a few extra words to make it less outstanding)